# Make Travis build a branch which has the branch being pushed to as a submodule and run a script

Tags: git, travis-ci

We have a repo (I'll call it $Main) which we build with another repo ($Sub) as a submodule. We currently use Travis for automated tests, although I am happy to use a different framework if there is one suitable.

I would like to have automated benchmarks such that when a commit is pushed to the master branch in $Sub,  automatically builds the master branch of $Main with the master branch of $Sub as a submodule, and runs a benchmarking script (bash or Python).

This script may take some time to finish (~1 hr, maybe more) and so I don't want it to be necessary for the build to pass, but I do want it to produce a .csv with the results and be able to access this.

How could I go about doing this? I have taken a look at git-hooks and Travis's build matrix but I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way yo trigger build at Travis for a different repository from what you pushed. You can trigger a build by pushing to a superproject but not to a subproject.

You can try to us [Travis CI API](https://developer.travis-ci.com/) to trigger a build. To automate this you also need a [push web-hook at Github](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-webhooks) for the subproject repository so that when you push to the subproject Github triggers the hook and the hook triggers a build for the superproject.